# Чтение DBF в Java

Tags: java, dbf

Есть DBF файл с определенным набором полей. Записей в таблице около 50 тысяч. Какие есть библиотеки для чтения данных из DBF в какой-то курсор или XML, JSON?

В общем мне нужно прочитать данные из DBF и вывести в XML или JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый популярный - javadbf. Напрямую в XML и JSON вы не выведете, а только сделаете маппинг в ваши java классы. Если вы хотите сохранить результат в XML и JSON, то дополнительно воспользуйтесь маршалерами вроде JAX-B.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ссылку откуда ее скачать?

Comment: Мы используем:<dependency>
    <groupId>com.linuxense</groupId>
    <artifactId>javadbf</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency> Но насколько мне известно есть версии свежее, возможно от других авторов.